# how do we organize our apps in itunes library

Tags: iphone, itunes

is there anyway to arrange or organize our apps in the itunes library?

I mean i have well a ton of apps and it really helps if i could put them in folders / lists / or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - there is nothing in iTunes to make it easier. You can also use [Xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id422352214?mt=12) and the [iPhone configuration utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) to get a little more screen real estate, but managing apps is still fairly simplistic. The configuration utility does make it possible to automate installing several apps, so that's a step in the right direction for some.

I've filed [bugs](http://bugreporter.apple.com) and [sent feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) asking for more screen real-estate in iTunes to start making app management easier.
[image]

They have a 'Use Full Window for iTunes Store' view so it's not inconceivable they might do the same for iOS management at some point. Feel free to link to my picture in your bug report or feedback if you also want to ask Apple for this change.

http://skitch.com/mbrad/fgj28/itunes-managing-ios-apps

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 4.0, it is possible to organize your app icons into folders: just drag one icon on top of another, it will automatically create a folder for you.

If you have tons of icons to move around, you can be slightly more efficient in iTunes by  using `SHIFT` to multi-select icons (or folders). Then drag them all at once onto another screen, or into an existing folder (or out of an existing folder).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that regardless of settings, playlists and even the Library (if it's enabled) ignore all apps, and dragging apps to manual playlists doesn't seem possible. So the only options you have are those that are built-in, such as viewing the apps as a list (View>as List), selecting which columns are available (View>View Options) and sorting by the available columns.